# Transfer a adjacent matrix to adjacent linked list of type Node

Tags: java, graph, linked-list

I'm doing an assignment on transfer the adjacent matrix to an adjacent linked list of type Node. This is the example input and output

```
Input:
int [][] matrix = {{0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1 ,0}}

Output:
0: Node 1 -> Node 3
1: Node 0
2: Node 3
3: Node 1 -> Node 2
```

This is what I did so far

The node class:

```
class Node{
    //attribute
    private int index;

    //constructor
    Node(){
        //basic constructor
    }

    //parametize constructor
    Node(int index){
        this.index = index;
    }

    //accessors
    public int getIndex(){
        return this.index;
    }

    //mutators
    public void setIndex(int tmpIndex){
        this.index = tmpIndex;
    }

    //method to print node
    public void printNode(){
        System.out.println(" -> Node " + this.index);
    }
}
```

The graph class to convert matrix to linked list

```
import java.util.*;
class MyGraph{
    //attributes
    LinkedList<Node> adjListArray[];
    private int v; //vertex

    //basic constructor
    MyGraph(){ //initialize empty graph
        this.v = 0;
        this.adjListArray = new LinkedList[this.v];
    }


    //transform an adjacent matrix to an adjacent matrix
    public void matrixToList(int [][] matrix){
        //initialize number of vertices
        this.v = matrix[0].length;

        //create a new list for each vertex
        for(int i = 0; i<this.v; i++){
            adjListArray[i] = new LinkedList<>();
        }

        for(int i=0; i<this.v; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<this.v; j++){
                if(matrix[i][j] == 1){
                    adjListArray[i].add(new Node(j));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //print method
    public void displayAdjListArray(){
        Node node = new Node();
        for(int i = 0; i<this.v; i++){
            System.out.print(i+": ");
            for(Node j : adjListArray[i]){
                j.printNode();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the main class for testing:

```
import java.util.*;

class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyGraph graph = new MyGraph();

        int [][] array = {{0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1 ,0}};
        graph.matrixToList(array); 
        System.out.println("Adjacency List: "); 
  
        graph.displayAdjListArray();
    }
}
```

So when I run my code, I get an exception of index out of bounds. Can you guys help me out with this problem, I'm just new to data structures like this so any idea that I can improve my code is appreciated. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in the constructor:

```
public MyGraph() { // initialize empty graph
    this.v = 0;
    this.adjListArray = new LinkedList[this.v];
}
```

You create with length `0` then you assign `this.v` with `matrix[0].length` which is `4`.

```
// initialize number of vertices
this.v = matrix[0].length;
```

This causes the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.v; i++) { 
    adjListArray[i] = new LinkedList<>();
}
```

You can change the constructor to initialize `v` and `adjListArray` with the right length:

```
public MyGraph(int v) { // initialize empty graph
    this.v = v;
    this.adjListArray = new LinkedList[this.v];
}
```